Power BI Refresh Synapse Web Activity
I'm trying to refresh a Power BI dataset using Azure Synapse's web activity by making a POST request as detailed in this [tutorial](https://www.tackytech.blog/how-to-refresh-power-bi-datasets-from-data-factory-with-managed-identity/. However, I'm encountering an "ItemNotFound" error despite following the instructions closely.
{
  "errorCode": "2108",
  "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"ItemNotFound\",\"message\":\"Dataset xxxxxxx is not found! Please verify datasetId is correct and user have sufficient permissions.\"}}",
  "failureType": "UserError",
  "target": "Web1"
}

Steps I've followed:

Configured the managed identity in Azure Synapse.
Configured Powerbi Tenant settings.
[
Set up the web activity to use the POST method with the URL for dataset refresh.

Verified dataset ID and permissions.

Despite these steps, the dataset refresh fails with the above error. Could anyone help me understand what might be going wrong here or if there are additional settings I need to verify?

What access has the managed identity being given within the workspace hosting the report?

contributor @Nandan


Dataset xxxxxxx is not found! Please verify datasetId is correct and user have sufficient permissions.

If your Workspace Id and Dataset Idyou used to be wrong in the API, then you might face this issue While calling refresh API for Power BI.

In the example above, we can see that the identifier appearing after “groups” refers to the workspace, and the one appearing after “datasets” is the identifier of our dataset, you need to use this id's in your API.
Also refer this document for better understanding Refresh Power BI Datasets with ADF or Synapse (SP)
